# Python: check the order of classes in multiple inheritance

Tags: python, django, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

In my framework I must assure that when a class inherits from ClassA, it must inherit also from ClassB, with ClassB following ClassA (in order to make overridden methods work [in Django forms]). E.g.

```
class MyClass(ClassA, ClassB) --> correct

class MyClass(ClassA) --> wrong

class MyClass(ClassB, ClassA) --> wrong
```

is there a way to make ClassA check that it is followed by ClassB (on startup or at runtime)?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of requiring a specific inheritance order, provide a `ClassC` that uses the right order *instead*:

```
class ClassC(ClassA, ClassB):
```

You *can* verify base classes with a metaclass, but that is overkill when a simple base class will do. A metaclass on `ClassA` would be called for subclasses of `ClassA` as well, then you simply test the `bases` parameter for the right orderings.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it after defining the classes. It uses `mro()` method.
If you have something like this

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(object):
    pass

class C(A,B):
    pass
```

If you print the output of `mro` you get the following.

```
print(A.mro(), B.mro(), C.mro())
([<class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>], 
[<class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>], 
[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>])
```

A way could be:

```
if C.mro()[1] == A.mro()[0] and C.mro()[2] == B.mro()[0]:
    go ahead
else:
    raise Exception
```